# Receiving a warning when installing pipenv and the pipenv command not being recognized by CMD

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I tried to install pipenv. But it returns an error. And pipenv command is not recognized by CMD.

Error:
`WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location. WARNING: The scripts pipenv-resolver.exe and pipenv.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

I uninstalled and then installed pipenv and virtualenv, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was said in the warning, you should add 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' to your Path variable. [Here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) is the guide how to do it.